# Programmer-Defined Exception Class problem

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to implement the code sample from a text book. It is trying to create an inherited Exception class from exception with code below.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TargetNotFoundException: public exception {
    public :
        TargetNotFoundException(const string& message = "")
            : exception("Target not found: " + message.c_str()){ } // end constructor
}; // end TargetNotFoundException
```

The constructor provides a way for a throw statement to identify the condition that caused the exception. For example, the statement

```
throw TargetNotFoundException (target + " not found in a box!");
```

invokes the constructor of TargetNotFoundException. The message given to the constructor is returned by the method what that is inherited from the class exception. Thus, a catch block, such as the following one, can access the message:

```
catch(TargetNotFoundException except) {
cout << except.what() << endl; 
}
```

If target has the value "glasses" when this block executes, the output is `Target not found: glasses not found in a box!`

However, there is a compilation error stating that:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char [19]'
      and 'const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::value_type *'
      (aka 'const char *'))
            : exception("Target not found: " + message.c_str()){ } // end constructor
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `+` operator that takes two C strings as parameters. Simply remove `.c_str()` from your code

```
exception("Target not found: " + message){ }
```

Presumably just a typo from your text book.

Comment: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::exception'
            : exception("Target not found: " + message){ } // end constructor
              ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @MervynLee Hmm, seems your book has more problems than I realised. Your compiler is correct there is no constructor of `std::exception` that takes a string. You could change `exception` to `logic_error` for instance.

Comment: Yeah inherit logic_error instead of Exception solved the issue. Can we conclude that it is better to inherit logic_error instead of Exception as we have 2 family of exceptions -> logic_error and runtime_error?

Comment: @MervynLee I've never been particularly convinced by the standard exception classes. Exception processing is so app specific that I just do whatever seems right on a case by case basis.